# Javascript add new field with value to specific object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array of objects from a json like this

```
{  
   "images":[  
      {  
         "childFolder":[  
            {  
               "name":"Trước",
               "_id":"5ccbc1e4af2be32acd1da1dd"
            },
            {  
               "name":"Sau",
               "_id":"5ccbc1e4af2be32acd1da1dc"
            },
            {  
               "name":"X-Quang",
               "_id":"5ccbc1e4af2be32acd1da1db"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to add a field test with value yes like so

> "test": "yes"

To an object with `"name" = "Sau"` using javascript

How can i do this? 
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: expected output would be {"name":"Sau", "_id":"5ccbc1e4af2be32acd1da1dc","test":"yes"} and other object still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the array and then check for name "Sau" and update the object.

```js
let obj = {"images":[{"childFolder":[{"name":"Trước","_id":"5ccbc1e4af2be32acd1da1dd"},{"name":"Sau","_id":"5ccbc1e4af2be32acd1da1dc"},{"name":"X-Quang","_id":"5ccbc1e4af2be32acd1da1db"}]}]};

obj.images.forEach(img => img.childFolder.forEach(v => {
  if(v.name === "Sau") v.test = "yes";
}));

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to loop an entire array, use `find()` instead. It will give you a better performance.

```
const obj = yourObject

obj.images
   .find(image => image.childFolder)
   .childFolder
   .find(person => person.name == 'Sau')
   .test = "yes"
```